# The concept of OOP in Lua, how do you utilise it efficiently? Any idea?

Tags: object-oriented

Let's say that I have a `Person` class. The person can eat, swim, and sleep. Basically, I do `Person:Eat()` and he eats and so on. Now what if he has a set of martial arts he can use? How would I do that?

Would it be like `Person.martialArts.Karate:Kick()` to perform a karate kick?

Or would it be better to have martialArts as it's own class where you would use it like `martialArts:Kick(Person.name)` and pass in person?

How exactly would this be best designed so that it can be as efficient as possible?

I'm really new to OOP. Help would be appreciated.

I've read about OOP but they're not very specific on examples of implementation.

Comment: Since you have no prior experience with OOP, I recommend that you grab a good book and take advantage of the many resources that are already available on the web.  As your question currently stands, any good answer amounts to an in-depth tutorial, something we don't do here.

Comment: Lua fully allows OOP. If you have a specific question about how to follow OOP principles we can help, but this is too broad.

Comment: Can you tell me how I would adopt my example above using OOP principles then? I just want an example of how to incorporate OOP w/person & martial arts.

Comment: While the others on here have suggested that you consult excellent resources like books on OOP, I would suggest another approach. Why do you want to use OOP? Does it solve some problem or design architecture concern in your application? (i.e. is it really, truly needed?) If you are looking to just follow "buzzword" trends then I would suggest to rethink if you really need to use OOP. Every programming paradigm has its place and purposes from OOP to functional to imperative to declarative and it is better to the pick the one that solves your problem versus is the sexiest.

Comment: What constitutes a good design approach strongly depends on what you are trying to accomplish and what constraints you're under. Your example is completely without context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think this question can be answered in terms of OOP design in games.

I don't know LUA, so I'll just do pseudo code. (maybe someone can edit?)

The construct Person.MartialArts.Kick() or even Person.MartialArts.Kick(otherPerson) in the context of a game where people fight each other doesnt work well.

A Method on an object can return a value and alter the properties of that object. But in general its bad practice to affect the variables you pass in to the method or other objects you have in the game.

The effects of the Kick action should be we assume to damage the person kicked. You probably want to work out the damage based on the properties of the person doing the kicking!

lets say our kick function is something like:

```
Target.HitPoints -= (Kicker.Strength * 2 - Target.Armour)
```

We dont want to change the Targets Hitpoints directly, so we can add a Method

```
function Person:ReceiveDamage(damage)
    self.Hitpoints = self.Hitpoints - (damage - self.Armour)
end
```

Only the Kicker knows his own strength so we add:

```
function Person:Kick(target)
    target.ReceiveDamage(self.Strength * 2)
end
```

Now we have the basics of OOP, the object encapsulates its properties and Exposes method for the progam to manipulate.

But we can further assume that the person can only Kick if they know the requisite martial art. This complicates things. A Person cant have Methods that only some Persons have and MartialArt isnt effected by a Kick. Furthermore the progam making the Kick call, wont know if the Person doing the kicking can kick or not! So we have to get inventive

We make a base type MartialArt and give it the method

```
int MartialArt.AttackDamage(string type, Person attacker)
```

We make a new class Karate, which inherits from MartialArt and override the AttackDamage Method.

```
int Karate.AttackDamage(string type, Person attacker)
{
    if(type == "kick")
    {
         return this.Kick(attacker);
    }
    return 0;
}

int Karate.Kick(Person attacker)
{
    return attacker.Strength * 2;
}
```

now we can have

```
Person.MartialArt = new Karate();
```

and

```
Person.Attack(string type, Person target)
{
    var damage = this.MartialArt.Attack(type, this);
    target.ReceiveDamage(damage);
}
```

now the person can attack another player, and if he knows the martial art with that attack the player will take the right amount of damage.

You can have lots of Person each with different martial arts. The MartialArt sub class knows all about how to calculate the damage and what attacks it can do.

The person knows how to take damage and how to perform an attack.

You can see how this makes things easier to edit. lets say we have some Persons who have a sheild as well.

We can make a new class PersonWithShield which inherits from Person and override its ReceiveDamage Method

```
PersonWithShield.ReceiveDamage(int damage)
{
    if(!this.ShieldIsUp)
    {
        this.HitPoints -= damage;
    }
}
```

Everything will work correctly and we didnt have to change our Kick function to know about shields, armour, blocking or anything else we might dream up

Comment: I think your answer is very good and thorough, however it misses some of the fundamental differences with Lua vs the C language (C#?) you use as an example. Lua does not really have the concept of classes, interfaces, etc. because it does something similar to JavaScript with Prototype inheritance. The biggest difference being that Lua is a scripting language versus a "hard-core" programming language like the C family languages.

Comment: while that is true, it does have classes and inheritance. all my exampels should apply

Comment: I've updated the first two functions, although I think its less clear without the type info

Comment: I was just noting those points because the dominant majority of OO designs usually use those tools to achieve the flexible and functional designs OOP is known for. Lua has variations of those tools that can cause OOP to be less than optimal as the correct design choice. At least in theory (everything has pro's and cons). Aside, I don't think the Lua code loses any clarity, but rather enhances it for those who know Lua more than the C family languages. Good job though. Just pointing out some things for future readers. :)